# ReflectionException in Container.php line 741: Class view does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.1, homestead

I'm working on a Laravel 5.1 project with Homestead. I shelled into my Vagrant machine and ran the Composer Update command in an attempt to try to update my project and now I get the following error:

```
    1. in Container.php line 741
    2. at ReflectionClass->__construct('view') in Container.php line 741
    3. at Container->build('view', array()) in Container.php line 631
    4. at Container->make('view', array()) in Application.php line 674
    5. at Application->make('Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory') in Container.php line 842
    6. at Container->resolveClass(object(ReflectionParameter)) in Container.php line 805
    7. at Container->getDependencies(array(object(ReflectionParameter)), array()) in Container.php line 776
    8. at Container->build('Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession', array()) in Container.php line 631
    9. at Container->make('Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession', array()) in /home/vagrant/Sites/laravel-basics/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php line 674
   10. at Application->make('Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession') in Pipeline.php line 123
   11. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
   12. at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
   13. at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
   14. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
   15. at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
   16. at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
   17. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
   18. at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
   19. at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'),  array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
   20. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
   21. at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
   22. at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
   23. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
   24. at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
   25. at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
   26. at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
   27. at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

I'm not sure what broke. I had already been working in Laravel 5.1 and Composer was running just fine. I feel that I have two basic options: 1) try to revert back tot he previous version of Composer or 2) revert to a previous version of my project. However, is there a simpler fix for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that you have **Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider** listed in the list of providers in your **config/app.php** file.

Apparently there is no **view** service in the container and this is the provided that sets it up.

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much.

Comment: The error came up in my case when I tried to update syntax from  (just one example) `'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider',` to `Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,`

Comment: I made sure it exists but still getting the error :(

Answer (score 33):

I've encountered this error message twice now, so I'm putting the solution here in case I have to google it some time in the future.

This error sometimes occurs because the "/bootstrap/cache" directory isn't writable. Hence, it can't compile a view. The solution is to chmod that directory so that it can be written to.

Voila. You're welcome, Future Me.

Comment: Thanks past me! You really saved my bacon this time.

Comment: This helped me :)

Comment: Thanks, why can't they just put an error that indicates this!

Comment: upvote +20 - or in my particular case the directory had been removed and it does not attempt to create it

Comment: Put a Donation link here and you shall become rich :). You just saved my morning!

Comment: @JordanLapp, you made my day! Thank you very much!

Comment: You are a legend

Answer (score 1):

For my future reference:

This can happen for a few reasons. Most common,

- `bootstrap/cache` is not writable.
- Missing `config/view.php` or this file has a syntax error.
- Try with `composer dumpautoload -o`
- On `config/app.php`, `ViewServiceProvider` and `View` alias must NOT be commented out.

In artisan, you may not see the exact error. If so, go to the error line, and dump the stacktrace. In this case, the file will be , `Illuminate/Container/Container.php`, line 741 (or the line shown on your screen. Dump the original exception with `dd($e)`, and see where the error started from.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the file was not named correctly. The class was declared as :

```
class NoSessionAccessMiddleware {
```

but the file was named as `NoSessionAccess.php`, I just renamed the file to `NoSessionAccessMiddleware.php` and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, I tried the above solutions with no luck. After running composer dump-autoload, I discovered it was because I had forgotten to install a package (Laravel Excel) I had setup on my dev server that wasn't yet loaded on the production server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating my projects namespace. I had to update the composer.json file:

```
 "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "myforms/app/"
    }
```

to:

```
 "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
```

On the server, in your source directory, run `composer update` then `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score -5):

This also can occur when the permissions on the 'bootstrap' folder and its contents are not right. For me chmodding to writable fixed it.

Comment: This answer duplicates what https://stackoverflow.com/a/35833239/470749 already says.